# Completely wiped out the OS on my ZTE phone and now it boots to Team Win Recovery Project. What do I do to fix it?

Tags: twrp, operating-system, zte

I wiped out the OS on my Android ZTE. Now, whenever I power on my device, the only thing that comes up is the third-party application "Team Win Recovery Project". It is showing all types of reboot options and I don't know what to do from this point.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: TWRP is a custom recovery which can be used to install custom ROMs. You just need to find a custom ROM (or the original firmware). Both have to match exactly your device model.